# Figures aligning

Tags: alignment

Can anyone please help to solve theis probelm.
In case of combining several figures in to 1, but seperatley. how to align them?
the following the exmaple. i did it but the figues are not aligned.
The cose is also present below and the figure which i made is unalgined can be seen in the atachement.
Thanks[image: image is unalinged. i actually combined the eps files but its not alligned when i get the reuslt]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{CJK}
%\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm} \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17.5cm} \setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\newpage
\begin{figure*}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig1.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig2.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig3.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig4.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig5.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig6.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig7.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8.cm]{fig8.eps}
\vspace{6mm}


\end{centering}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we get access to the figures?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use absolute widths in the optional argument of `\includegraphics`; instead, use relative widths, such as `[width=0.475\textwidth]`.
- Use `\hfill` directives to maximize the horizontal separation of graphs within a row.
- Insert a bit of whitespace between rows via, say, `\medskip` directives.

Aside: (a) Don't manipulate low-level parameters such as `\baselinestretch` directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue a suitable `\setstretch` directive. (b) There is a `center` environment in LaTeX, but no `centering` environment. It is true that issuing the instructions `\begin{centering}` and `\end{centering}` do not precipitate warning or error messages. However, that's due to a quirk in Latex syntax that just happens to work in your favor.

Here's how I would adapt your code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,demo]{article} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{CJK}
%\usepackage{rotating}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} % don't manipulate this low-level parameter directly
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm} \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5cm} \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17.5cm} \setlength{\textheight}{23.5cm}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\newpage
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig1.eps}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig2.eps}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig3.eps}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig4.eps}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig5.eps}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig6.eps}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig7.eps}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{fig8.eps}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```